# Can modern browsers switch from HTML to a simpler syntax?

Tags: html, json, web, browser, syntax

After I came up with this idea, I did some research and found this, https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-the-Internet-switch-to-JSON-instead-of-HTML

The answers make sense, except that I think modern browsers should be able to make the switch smoothly.

Say we have the following html,

```
<div class="basket col">
  <div class="btn">Run Robot</div>
  <p>Next Fruit is
    <span>
      some text here
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

And say We convert it to a simpler syntax (just for explaining the idea),

```
div class="basket col" <
  div class="btn" < Run Robot >
  p < Next Fruit is
    span < 
      some text here
    >
  >
>
```

Modern browsers can start supporting both syntaxes. The developers can then decide which syntax to use. If they don't want to support legacy browsers, they can start using the new syntax.

Are there any technical limitations to do this migration?

**FYI, I am not proposing a new syntax, I am asking why modern browsers wouldn't start supporting a minimal synatx like this, or a templating language like HAML or PUG?**

**And for the people who are downvoting**, can u guys at least make a comment on why this question is bad?

Comment: Or developers can use whatever they want and generate HTML based on it. That is what some already do. What is the advantage of your suggestion over HTML except for being less verbose?

Comment: @str Wouldn't that make the size of the html less? So we can get some advantage over slow networks. Are there any disadvantages to this approach?

Comment: If you're going to create something more minimal, at least be thorough and go with [HAML](http://haml.info) or something like it.

Comment: In general, *"why doesn't"* questions are rarely good questions. Usually it boils down to "because nobody did yet, why don't you?" This particular question has a more specific answer, but could still be boiled down to that.

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda Yes it would decrease the size. But there are usually other things you can do before reinventing every single Browser/IDE/parser/template-engine/... For example minification, compression, HTTP2, faster servers, geographically closer servers, CDNs, and much more.

Comment: @str That makes sense. However, there are already established syntax types like haml and pug which means we don't have to re-invent every single Browser/IDE/parser/template-engine. My question(updated) is, are there any technical limitations on doing this?

Comment: @deceze I updated the question. Thanks for pointing it out. My real question was not the opinions, but to know whether there are technical limitations.

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda Well, there is (AFAIK) no browser, no web scraper, and probably no template engine meant for websites that emits HAML that supports HAML. This is something almost everything in the toolchain would have to adapt to. This somehow remindes me of [xkcd: Standards](https://xkcd.com/927/) with the exception that there is only (sort of) one standard that is supported by everything.

Comment: @str That makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no inherent technical limitation, but: it took decades to get the entire web industry on the same page to support one specific HTML syntax, and web developers need to produce markup which is ***backwards compatible*** with existing browsers and any other consumer of HTML until the existing infrastructure ages away and is replaced with new infrastructure which all supports your NewMarkupLanguage™®.

It's a trivial matter to come up with some new markup language, it's a gargantuan task that will take another decade or five to get that new language adopted by everyone. The impedance here is compatibility, and the advantage is simply not that great as to be worth it. gzipping your HTTP response solves most of the problem.